# Making work play2-auth standard sample

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to make work the `play2-auth` standard sample, excluding authorizations - just authentication/login.

I'm getting in the form the following error in the `@helper.form` line:

> type mismatch;  found   : play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]
>   required: play.api.mvc.Call

```
@(form: Form[Option[session2.Account]])(implicit flash: Flash)
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

  @helper.form(session2.ManageSession.authenticate) {  // <-- here's the error

    <h1>Sign in</h1>

    @form.globalError.map { error =>
      <p class="error">
        @error.message
      </p>
    }
    @flash.get("success").map { message =>
      <p class="success">
        @message
      </p>
    }

    <p>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" 
            value="@form("email").value">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    </p>
    <p>
      <button type="submit" id="loginbutton">Login</button>
    </p>
  }
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is ManageSession.scala:

```
package session2

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import jp.t2v.lab.play2.auth._


object ManageSession extends Controller with LoginLogout with AuthConfigImpl {

  val loginForm = Form {
    mapping("email" -> text, "password" -> text)(Account.authenticate)
       (_.map(u => (u.email, "")))
      .verifying("Invalid email or password", result => result.isDefined)
  }

  def login = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.login(loginForm))
  }

  def logout = Action.async { implicit request =>
    // do something...
    gotoLogoutSucceeded
  }


  def authenticate = Action.async { implicit request =>
      loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        formWithErrors => Future.successful(BadRequest(views.html.main())),
        user => gotoLoginSucceeded(user.get.email)
      )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently passing to the form template helper the `Action` instance for `authenticate`, rather than the [`Call`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Call) instance that should be generated by its [reverse route](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRouting#Reverse-routing). A `Call` describes the URL and method of an action, as defined in your routes file, so you don't have to hardcode it everywhere.

First of all, put your `ManageSession` controller in the `controllers` package (as per Play's defaults - you can move it later but *I think* the reverse route generation relies on them being there, or in a subpackage.):

```
package controllers

...

object ManageSession extends Controller with LoginLogout with AuthConfigImpl {
  ...
}
```

Your `conf/routes` file should look something like this:

```
POST  /authenticate      controllers.ManageSession.authenticate
```

Then the reverse route `Call` object will be generated in `controllers.routes.ManageSession.authenticate`:

```
@helper.form(controllers.routes.ManageSession.authenticate) {
    ...
}
```

Note the **`routes`** subpackage in there!

The result should be HTML generated like so:

```
<form method="POST" action="/authenticate">
   ...
</form>
```

---

**Note**: in Play 2.5 and above, static (object) controllers are discouraged and do not work with the default (injected) routes generator. In this case the simplest option is just to make `ManageSession` a class instead of an object:

```
class ManageSession() extends Controller with LoginLogout with AuthConfigImpl {
  ...
}
```

Alternately, you could specify you want the `StaticRoutesGenerator` in your `build.sbt`:

```
routesGenerator := StaticRoutesGenerator
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an error `value ManageSession is not a member of object controllers.routes`, any idea what could be the reason? ManageSession is in package controllers

Comment: @ps0604 which version of Play are you using?

Comment: 2.5.2 with eclipse scala ide

Comment: See the note I've added about needing a non-static controller with the default routes generator.